# delete ocurrences that ocurr less than X time

Tags: vim, replace

I have a file with numbers. One number per line

```
1234
54332
54321
32452
1234
1234
54321
```

I want to delete every number that doesn't appear more than 3 times.

I was thinking about sorting and then joining lines and then delete the ones that don't have 3 words.

I think there is a better way but I don't know enough vim to do it.

Have any tip?

Comment: if I were doing this, I would call external awk. it would be easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I commented under your question, I would do it with awk. of course, vim can do it too, by a custom function, for example.

you could try this line:

```
%!awk '{a[$0]++}END{for(x in a)if(a[x]>3)for(y=1;y<=a[x];y++)print x}'
```

**note** that, your example is not so good, because there is no line "appear more than 3 times." If you add another `1234` line, the result of above command would be:

```
1234
1234
1234
1234
```

Comment: 2 questions (as I never use awk). 1. Does this work on arbitrary lines (ie lines that arn't numbers) 2. Are the lines sorted numerically when this is done?

Comment: 1: YES, works for any text. 2: it will break the original line sequence (order). it could sort the lines with some logic. if the sorting requirement is really complex, we still have vim buildin :sort and external sort. @FDinoff